# Is there a way of visualising a line in drake visualizer

Tags: drake

I am currently working with the compass-gait example. I am trying to visualise a planned path for a robot. Is there a way to visualise a few lines dynamically during the simulation on the visualizer as the robot traces a path?

I am looking into publishing lcm messages directly [from here](https://openhumanoids.github.io/director/user_guide/tree_viewer_interface.html#viewer-tree), but I am finding it a little hard to get the right sequence. Is there a sub-module I can check to get a better idea about this?

Comment: I think using the RemoteTreeViewer interface is the right direction here -- you could check out [this C++ interface](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/spartan/tree/master/src/RemoteTreeViewer) as a reference on how to get lines (and other geometry) to stick. The "publishLine" method in [this file in particular](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/spartan/blob/master/src/RemoteTreeViewer/RemoteTreeViewerWrapper.cpp) ought to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. Also, is there a way of editing the scene, i.e. things like the grid size/position and camera angle from a separate program? I could not find any examples in the documentation, and from the source, https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/director/blob/master/src/vtk/DRCFilters/vtkGridSource.cxx it looks like if i want to go deeper I will have to look into the vtk package